# How to Define Custom Conditional Expression Primaries in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, directory-structure, syntax

How would I redefine and/or define new [conditional expression primaries](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html) in bash?  For example, I would like a primary that tests for the existence of an empty directory.  Of course, it would be preferable to do this with only one primary, but if that is not possible, then two primaries is also acceptable.  As an example, I would like to be able to accomplish this:

```
    if [ -DZ $HOME/dir ]; # true if directory the path is an empty directory
      then echo "$HOME/dir doesn't have any non-hidden files or directories!"
    fi
```

Comment: See https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2016-04/msg00016.html

Answer (score 3):

To add your own `test` predicates, you would have to modify the `bash` sources for the built-in `[` command.  This is probably not what you want to do, as it would result in hopelessly non-portable scripts.  You may instead employ a shell function:

```bash
isemptydir () (
    shopt -s nullglob
    shopt -s dotglob

    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        echo 'isemptydir: Empty or missing argument' >&2
        return 1

        # could instead do: set .
        # this would use the current directory as the "default" one
    fi

    if [ -d "$1" ]; then
        # note: above test fails on inaccessible dirs --> "not empty"

        set -- "${1%/}"/*
        [ "$#" -eq 0 ]
        # note: above test succeeds on unlistable dirs --> "empty"           
    fi
)

if isemptydir "$mydir"; then
    printf 'Directory "%s" is empty\n' "$mydir"
else
    printf '"%s" is not a directory, or is not empty\n' "$mydir"
fi
```

The function tests whether the given argument is the name of a directory.  If it is, it counts the number of names (not just files) that are available in the directory, including hidden names, and compares this to zero.  The return status of the test that is performed last is the return status of the function.

---

You could possibly overload the `[` or `test` commands with your own functions, but that would also potentially be problematic.

Comment: Note that it will also claim that a directory which you don't have read access to is empty (see also https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2016-04/msg00049.html). You may need to treat  `/` or an empty `$dir` specially (on some systems, `//*` has a special meaning).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I think I possibly have mitigated some of that. An unreadable directory is "empty" in the sense that the process cannot access names in it (that's a "design decision"). However, there's an issue with directories _inside_ inaccessible directories (would be "non-empty" with this code). Oh well.

Comment: This answer advocating an *ad hoc* script is similar to [Debian Bug report logs - #385069  moreutils: Please add "dirempty" command](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=385069).